# Cannot Manipulate DOM of new tab created via chrome.tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

Here is what I did:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:msg.url}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        runAt:"document_end", 
        allFrames:true,
        code:"var ready = function(fn){ if(typeof fn!== 'function') return ; if(document.readyState === 'complete') {return fn();}  if(document.readyState === 'interactive'){ return fun(); };}; ready(function() { console.log(document.querySelector('#rso h3 a')) alert('yes'); document.querySelector('#rso h3 a').click(); });"

    });
});
```

But it seems that the js runs in isolated environment so i cannot manipulate the DOM,  is there any workaround?

I also tried the `code` attribute to contain just the following snippet

```
document.querySelector('#rso h3 a').click();
```

PS: If the `code` attribute is, for instance a call to `alert()` function, it woks flawlessly.

Comment: What's the actual nonworking code? Are you trying to access a variable set by the page? Also, the site may add its content dynamically, so you might need a MutationObserver or setTimeout.

Comment: @wOxxOm : Edited the post and added the code. The code has extra part which is to ensure that the code runs after DOM is ready.

Comment: What's `document.addEventListener('interactive')`?

Comment: @haibara-ai check out https://gomakethings.com/a-native-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-method/  for your question

Comment: @cipher, I guess you mean check if `document.readyState` is `interactive`. There is no `interactive` event for `document`, AFAIK.

Comment: @HaibaraAi , So i changed the code, to look it like this: (updated in the question above too), but it still has no effects.

    `code:"var ready = function(fn){ if(typeof fn!== 'function') return ; if(document.readyState === 'complete') {return fn();}  if(document.readyState === 'interactive'){ return fun(); };}; ready(function() { console.log(document.querySelector('#rso h3 a')) alert('yes'); document.querySelector('#rso h3 a').click(); });"`

Comment: You have `fun()` where there should be `fn()`. _No fun allowed!_

Comment: @Xan Thanks for spotting that, but I now changed the code to something like this:

`code:"var ready = function(fn){ document.onreadystatechange = function(){ if (document.readyState==='interactive'){ return fn(); } }; }; ready(function() { console.log(document.querySelector('#rso h3 a')); alert('yes'); document.querySelector('#rso h3 a').click(); });"`

But I still get nothing! :/

Comment: Check the page's console for errors in your "simplest" case (no `ready` wrapping).

Comment: @Xan , When i just replace `fun()` with `fn()` , the javascript runs before page load, (or in isolated environment), so I get the alert but the queryselector's output is null.

Comment: `document_end` guarantees that all static DOM is loaded. So listening to document state events won't help. The element is created dynamically and it doesn't correspond to those events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118234/discussion-between-xan-and-cipher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Xan and our discussion on the topic, the problem was solved by using the combination of `setInterval` and `clearInterval` with the `code` attribute as follows:

```
code: "var intrvl = null; function fn(){ var a = document.querySelector('#rso h3 a'); if(a !== null){ clearInterval(intrvl); a.click(); } }; intrvl = setInterval(fn, 500);"
```

The problem was that the particular page I was trying to inject this javascript had created the elements I wanted to manipulated dynamically, and `document_end` only guaranteed that all static DOM was loaded, I had to do this workaround.

Another way could be to use Mutation Libraries in Javascript or raw `MutationObserver` API.